# Sql issue in calculating formulas

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem when i'm trying to calculate in a view a formula whose result is smaller than 1. 
e.g. I have the next formula: `Arenda*TotalArea/10000 as TotalArenda`
If I have Arenda=10 and TotalArea=10 I get TotalArenda=0,00 when normally should be 0.01
Thanks

Comment: What are types of Arenda and TotalArea?

Comment: @oryol They are numeric(12,2) type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Arenda = 10.0 and TotalArea = 10.0 instead of 10 and 10.  This will force SQL not to use integer math and you will get your needed accuracy.

In fact, the only way I can get 0.0 as the result is if the Arenda is 10 (integer) while at least one of TotalArea or 10000 contain a decimal and a trailing 0, and only if I override order of operations by grouping using parentheses such as

```
select 10.0* (10/10000) as blah
```

If all are integers you get 0.  If all contain decimals you get 0.01.  If I remove the parentheses, I get 0.01 if ANY of them are non-integer types.

If precision is highly important I would recommend you cast to decimals and not floats:

```
select CONVERT(decimal(10,2), Arenda) * CONVERT(decimal(10,2), TotalArea) / 10000.0
```

Comment: You're right, TotalArea was integer, now I realised.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are using colunns, so changing the type may not be feasible.  SQL Server does integer division on integers (other databases behave differently).  Try one of these:

```
cast(Arenda as float)*cast(TotalArea as float)/10000
```

or:

```
Arenda*TotalArea/10000.0
```